# expo-notifications has a serious delay

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, expo, expo-notifications

guys. I'll make this short. When this is being invoked:
const allNotifications = await Notifications.getAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();

in redux-thunk action function, after changing date or time in phone settings and relaunching the app, it takes up to 30 seconds to await for allNotifications.

The problem appears only after changing date or time in phone settings, but what doest it wait for, If at the same moment there are no notifications created at all

react-native, expo-notifications, SQlite db.

Thanks everbody, who could help